# OWASP ZAP Error : "Too many active connections right now" [Docker Image]

Tags: linux, docker, user-interface, centos

ZAP is successfully running on docker container in GUI mode, but it is only allowing one active user at a time.Command I used to run the image:-

> docker run --name zap -u zap  -p 8080:8080 -p 8090:8090 -i owasp/zap2docker-stable zap-webswing.sh

How to increase the user limit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That seems like a webswing error not a ZAP issue. ZAP doesn't limit active connections by count.

If webswing's defaults aren't working out for you then you'll need to create a customized docker image or pass a modified config file to your command somehow. Checkout Max Connections and Session Mode in webswing's docs https://www.webswing.org/docs/2.6/config/swing.html#settings-overview

Comment: You were right. The problem was in the webswing config file. I only increased the active client value in it and it worked for me. Thanks once again.

Comment: Hello @ManishSharma could you please share how you managed to increase the active client value? we are running it in K8s with stable image. do we have to provide configmap for it?

Comment: @NitinGarg Just change the active client value in the configuration file of the webswing.

Comment: Thanks Manish ... we were able to correct it ... the actual variable is maxClients in my stable version